# Sampling from a Pandas DataFrame to match a continuous distribution of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a number of dataframes (41 in total) of varying sizes (min = <1000 rows, max = 125k rows). For each row in a dataframe, I have a column (that for illustrative purposes I'll call *count*) that counts over a number of elements in an adjacent column - something like this:

```
  DATAFRAME 1                     DATAFRAME 2
----------------              ----------------
 letters | Count               letters | Count
----------------              ----------------
  ABC    |   3                  ABCDE  |   5
  DEFG   |   4                  WXYZAB |   6
  AB     |   2                    AB   |   2
  YZ     |   2             ABCDEFGHIJ  |   10
----------------              ----------------
```

However, the distribution of *count* is not the same in every dataframe (ignoring the values in the example above). This is skewing performance in a downstream task. What I want to do is take advantage of the size disparity between the dataframes, and sample from the larger dataframes such that their distribution of *count* approximates to the target (smaller) dataframe. **How do I go about this?**

Something I had been thinking of is detailed [here](https://michaeljsanders.com/2017/03/24/stratify-continuous-variable.html). Basically, we bin the target distribution (dataframe1['Count']) and use that to create a stratified subset using `train_test_split`. That seems like it would work, but appears to be a workaround given that I am not intended to create a train/test split in the data (although we could just be arguing over semantics here).

Is there a proper process/name/package that tackles this problem explicitly? I've been trying to understand kernel density estimators as a potential solution to this problem. Would that be an alternative way to approach this problem?

Comment: concatenate all your dataframe together, from which explicity sample a certain number of rows for each of the `letters`?

Comment: Does it matter that the `Count` variable is a count, or could we think of it as any other variable, but one that you need distributed in the same way among all the DataFrames?

Comment: @semblable the real-world problem I'm trying to get through is a count variable. I suppose in reality what matters is that its a distribution of a continuous variable I'm looking to mirror.